# Change default timeout okhttp client using jetpack compose

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, okhttp

I am using API from rapidapi.com. The response from the api provider is sometimes very long. Caused application timeout on okhttp client. I ask please how to change the default timeout value on okhttp to 30 seconds

```
 LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        val client = OkHttpClient()

        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://plantwise.p.rapidapi.com/plant/?plant_type=$plantName")
            .get()
            .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", "xxxxx.rapidapi.com")
            .build()

        val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            client.newCall(request).execute()
        }

        val responseData = response.body?.string()
        if (responseData != null) {
            plantData = gson.fromJson(responseData, PlantData::class.java)
        }

    }
```

I've tried this way but still can't

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Set the connection timeout
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Set the read timeout
    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Set the write timeout
    .build()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where the default timeouts are not being applied correctly, you can try setting the timeouts directly on the Call object that you're making. Here's an example:

```
val call = client.newCall(request)
call.timeout().timeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Set the timeout directly on the Call object
```